# Interceptor for HttpRequests made by aws API

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, api, authentication, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a project that uses cognito as an auth service to secure a serverless rest API made using nodeJS. I've successfully closed the API for non-authenticated clients. I now need to automatically inject a token in the header whenever i make a request from my Angular client.
What i tried is implementing an HttpInterceptor like this :

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Accept'       : 'application/json',
              'Authorization': `${this.authService.userToken}`,
              //#endregion
          },
          
        })
  

  return next.handle(req);
}
```

This always worked fine for me when using the standard angular HttpClient to make requests. But now as i'm using API from aws-amplify package to make request to my API.Gateway, these requests can't get intercepted like this.
Here's how i make requests :

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
.
.
.
 return API.get('apiName', '/users',{})
```

And these are not using the Angular HttpClient.

EDIT :
Also in app.module.ts :

```
providers : [{
    provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor,  --> My interceptor class
    multi   : true,
  }]
```

Anyone got an idea of how i can intercept these request to my API Gateway to inject the token?

Have a nice one !

Comment: [CathyAugust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5368983) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877625) saying "[https://github.com/claudiajs/example-projects/tree/master/intercepting-requests](https://github.com/claudiajs/example-projects/tree/master/intercepting-requests) You can check ClaudiaJS for a solution."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **Axios** for intercepting requests made using the aws-amplify package because the aws-amplify package uses Axios to make its requests.

> Axios is a Javascript library used to make HTTP requests from node.js
> or XMLHttpRequests from the browser and it supports the Promise API
> that is native to JS ES6. It can be used to intercept HTTP requests
> and responses and enables client-side protection against XSRF. It also
> has the ability to cancel requests.

In this case, create a new service for the Interceptor.

In **axios-interceptor.service.ts**,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AxiosInterceptorService {
    intercept() {
        axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
            request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
            request.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
            request.headers.Authorization = `${userToken}`;
            return request;
        });
    }
}

export function AxiosConfigFactory(axiosIntercept: AxiosInterceptorService): any {
  return () => axiosIntercept.intercept();
}
```

In **app.module.ts**,

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AxiosConfigFactory, AxiosInterceptorService } from './axios-interceptor-service.service';

providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: AxiosConfigFactory,
        deps: [AxiosInterceptorService],
        multi: true
    }
],
```

Furthermore, we can also handle error responses by using the below code inside the intercept() method.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    }, errorObject => {

    return Promise.reject(errorObj.response);
});
```

PS: I had a really hard time figuring this out. Even thought the answer is late, I hope it helps someone in the future :)

Comment: Even a year later, i've learned something. Thank you

Comment: Great, Even 2 years later your answer keep helping developers. You save my day. thanks