# Use angular interceptor for Aws amplify graphql Api request

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, interceptor

We need to implement angular interceptor for aws amplify graphql calls. We know that aws graphql calls use axios behind the scene, so we tried to implement axios interceptor in angular but It doesn't work.

We follow this solution [Interceptor for HttpRequests made by aws API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488595/interceptor-for-httprequests-made-by-aws-api) as well, but this function axios.interceptors.request.use() doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? You can't see graph requests passing through the interceptor?

Comment: Actually interceptor request function not executing for any api calls. So in short, thing happened.

Comment: I use Apollo Angular [link](https://apollo-angular.com/) to handle graphQL communication in my apps, it's a graphQL client.During the creation of an instance of Apollo i can define a graphQL interceptor that handle graphQL request, this could be a suitable solution for your case?

Comment: We are using aws appsync service and npm package aws-amplify for graphql calls. So cant use apollo. Need to use interceptor with aws-amplify package.

Comment: any other solution ?

Comment: @irfanbabar Did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Cristal Hi, It was long ago. Let me explain what I remember, we need to restrict some appsync apis base on user role. We couldn't implement interceptor directly, what we had done that we uses API.graph() with parameter like authMode, with help of that you can specific what kind of auth check you have to use for API.

But you can also use VTL, which is kind of resolver in AWS graphQL, but its little complicated. Thats why I don't prefer.

I hope above info may help you